# PEP8 standards on numerous variables

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I have to assign a large number of variables in my code. To the extent that they would not fit onto a single line.

A few idea on how to write the code were;

Option A.

```
(
    A, B, C,...
    ...Z
) = (
    1, 2, 3,...
    ...26
)
```

Option B.

```
A, B, C,...\
    ...Z =\
    1, 2, 3,...\
   ...26
```

Option C.

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
...
Z = 26
```

Does PEP8 have a preference between these options? Or is there any better solution to make this look clean?

Comment: As the emphasis in python is on self-documenting code and readability, I would use option C so it's explicit and clear. The other options are going to read messily. One other thing to consider, why do you need to declare so many variables at once? Are there any you can declare only when they are used, or that could be constants instead?

Comment: Problems with very many variables often turn out to be problems which can be elegantly solved with a `dict`. Of course, without context, this is just a wild guess.

Comment: What is the real use case for that? Maybe it's better to use `enum.Enum` for your purpose?

Comment: if you really want to go through pep 8 guidelines in your porject, i suppse it's better to use Pycharm IDE . it will show error where your code is missing guidelines. . here in problem go use Option 3

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The main reason for assigning lots of variables at once is because there is an if else statement which assigns them all to None in the else condition. I think I will go with option C as advised :)